# ¿Cómo hacer un arreglo con numeros aleatoreos pero en parejas?

Tags: c++

El arreglo se debe de llenar con números aleatorios pero en parejas.

Con parejas me refiero a que cuando los números aleatorios se generen, entre todos los números no pueden haber un número que se genere tres o más veces, ni tampoco solo una vez: debe tener su pareja.

Por ejemplo si se genera un 2, debe de existir otro 2.

Ejemplo: 2 2 4 4 5 5 6 6 8 8 9 9 pero deben quedar en desorden.

Ejemplo si el tamaño del vector es de 12 una posible salida podría ser:

```
8 4 3 8 2 9 7 4 2 3 9 7
```

Ya lo intenté de todas la maneras que se me ocurrieron y no lo logro.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
srand(time(NULL));
    int banderas[12];
    int conta =0;

        for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
        conta=0;
        banderas[i]=rand() % 12 + 1;
        cout<<banderas[i]<<"\n";
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
            if(banderas[i]==banderas[j]){
                conta++;
            }
        }
        if(conta<2){
            i--;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
        cout<<banderas[i]<<" ";
    }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: en parejas, a que te refieres? Por qué no lo logras? Te da fallos o no es el resultado esperado?  Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y como mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Un saludo

Comment: No veo que los números estén emparejados :O

Comment: Hola con mi código no logro obtener el resultado que es los números aleatorios en parejas

Comment: Adrian, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/75311/edit) la pregunta para explicarlo mejor. ese comentario no esclarece nada

Answer (score 2):

Puedes generar los números válidos de tu serie, en forma de pares:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 9);

std::vector<int> n(12);

for (int b = 0, e = n.size() / 2; b != e; ++b)
    n[b] = n[b + e] = b;
```

Y después mezclarlos:

```
std::shuffle(n.begin(), n.end(), gen);
```

Comment: editó su pregunta tras tu respuesta. lo de las parejas ha quedado mas explicado

Comment: ¬_¬ editando...

Comment: creo que te pasaste con los numeros. son 12 numeros y 6 parejas. hahaha

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo y ayudarme pero el asunto es que soy nuevo en esto y no tengo permitido usar cosas muy avanzadas o cosas que aun no se mencionen en clase, solo puedo usar cosas básicas de c++ para resolver el problema  como for, while, if o ese tipo de cosas.

Comment: `random` y `algorithm` son, o deberían ser, cosas muy básicas de C++. No pasa nada si a ti no te es útil esta respuesta (no la votes) pero podría servir de referencia a otros lectores.

Comment: Lo único que te falta indicar que la respuesta solo compila con C++11 o superior... que la pregunta no tiene etiqueta de C++11

Comment: Tampoco tiene etiqueta [tag:c] y usa librerías C ;) soy un poco *puñetero* en ese aspecto, a día de hoy nadie debería trabajar por debajo de C++11 ¡han pasado 6 años desde su aprobación! ¡y los compiladores ya lo implementan!

Comment: Lo se, pero sabes tan bien como yo que los cursos, la universidad y las empresas van a un ritmo y los estándares a otro

Answer (score 2):

Paso 1:

Rellenas el vector con los valores a pares. Además compruebas que el nuevo número a introducir no se encuentra en el vector. Así te garantizas de que cada número aparece exactamente 2 veces:

```
  srand(time(NULL));
  int banderas[12];

  for( int i=0; i<12; i++ ){
    int numero;
    do
    {
      numero = rand() % 12 + 1;
    } while( std::count(banderas,banderas+i,numero) != 0);

    banderas[i++] = numero;
    banderas[i] = numero;
  }
```

El do-while se usa para garantizar que no se introducen números ya usados.

Ahora el vector tendrá un contenido tal que:

```
4 4 10 10 6 6 12 12 7 7 1 1
```

Paso2: mezclamos el vector

```
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++ )
  {
    int nuevaPos;
    do {
      nuevaPos = rand() % 12;
    } while (nuevaPos == i );

    std::swap(banderas[i],banderas[nuevaPos]);
  }
```

Si quieres más mezcla puedes repetir varias veces el bucle...

Y ya está: vector mezclado y con números a pares:

```
12 10 1 4 6 4 6 12 10 7 1 7
```

NOTA Adicional:

`std::count` se puede sustituir por:

```
int Count(int* begin, int*end, int valor)
{
  int total = 0;
  for( ; begin != end; begin++ )
    total += ( *begin == valor );
  return total;
}
```

De tal forma que:

```
do
{
  numero = rand() % 12 + 1;
} while( Count(banderas,banderas+i,numero) != 0);
```

Y `std::swap` por:

```
void Swap(int& a, int& b)
{
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

tal que:

```
for(int i=0; i<12; i++ )
{
  int nuevaPos;
  do {
    nuevaPos = rand() % 12;
  } while (nuevaPos == i );

  Swap(banderas[i],banderas[nuevaPos]);
}
```

Comment: Esto no garantiza que no se repitan números en cantidades pares.

Comment: Lo que pide es que cada número aparezca exactamente dos veces... y esto lo garantiza :)

Comment: Ah, leí tu código mal, perdón.