# Usando el generador de números aleatorios en C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un programa que genere números aleatorios de un dígito. Si el usuario ingresa el mismo número es declarado el ganador.

El código me genera el siguiente error:

> c:\users\bella\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp(12):
>   warning C4244: `argumento`: conversión de `time_t` a `unsigned int`; posible pérdida de datos
>   c:\users\bella\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\project1\project1\source.cpp(13):
>   error C3861: `rnad`: no se encontró el identificador

Código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numero;
    int guess;

    srand(time(NULL));
    numero = rnad() % 10 + 1;
    system("cla");

    cout << "Bienvenido a la loteria" << 

    system("pause");

    while (guess != numero)
    {
        system("cla");
        cout << "Ingrese el numero de su boleto" << 
        cin >> guess;
    }
    system("cla");
    cout << "El numero de su boleto es el ganador" << 
    cout << "El numero ganador fue" << numero << 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te has equivocado al teclear. No es `rnad( )`, es `rand( )`.

Answer (score 2):

El **aviso** (que no error) es auto-explicativo:

> conversión de 'time_t' a 'unsigned int'; posible pérdida de datos.

Estas haciendo
    srand( time( NULL ) );

Cuando el *prototipo* de las funciones es:

```
time_t time( time_t * );
void srand( unsigned int );
```

Con tu código, conviertes el valor de retorno de `time( )` en el argumento de `srand( )`. Ambos tipos son **no son iguales**, aunque tienen cierta *compatibilidad*. El compilador *te obedece* y convierte el `time_t` en un `unsigned int`, pero te avisa de que el segundo **no es exactamente el mismo** que el primero, y que *puedes* tener problemas de perder información.

En tu caso concreto, puedes *ignorar* esa advertencia. Lo estas usando para conseguir secuencias de números aleatorias, y lo peor que puede pasar es que se repita el mismo valor en distintas partidas.

Como nota final: estas usando librerías de C. En esta reciente pregunta: [¿Cómo hacer un arreglo con numeros aleatoreos pero en parejas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/75311/23371) tienes algunas formas de generar números aleatorios *a la manera C++ de hacer las cosas*.

Answer (score 1):

Adicional al warning y al error, tambien debes corregir la llamada al sistema `system("cla")` que no existe y en su lugar podrias colocar `system("cls")` lo cual es una llamada al sistema para limpiar la pantalla.

Ademas colocar `endl;` luego de los cout que estas colocando parece ser tambien parte de tu *intención*. aunque tal vez te convenga usar `"\n"` como salto de linea.